# How is Regret defined for combinatorial optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, multiarmed-bandit

I have a combinatorial optimization problem, where I'm trying to find the global minimum (many local minima exist)

In principle, my agent can choose to be anywhere in the state space at any given step, but it doesn't know where the minimum is so it will have to take some educated guesses (hill-climb).

So far as I understand Regret, it is mean to compute your ``deficit" against the best possible steps you could have taken in hindsight.  However, it seems to me that in the combinatorial optimization case, the "best" course of action in hindsight is to immediately move to the global minimum, or at least remove all the steps that didn't make you closer to the global minimum.

This seems to be quite different than how I understand Regret in multi-armed bandits. Is Regret ill-defined in this setting, or is my understanding lacking?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is either ill-defined or unhelpful as a concept, for basically the reasons you give.

Another way to think about it is that regret is important in multiarmed bandit problems because the randomness in the return for any strategy is what makes the problem difficult. This means it makes sense to ask how well you could do without that randomness, and it's interesting that there are eventually zero-regret strategies.

In your problem, there isn't any randomness.  Now, for a Bayesian there is always randomness, so you could probably define a Bayesian analogue of the regret: given a prior distribution for the function you're trying to optimise, how well did you do compared to the strategy that minimises the posterior expected loss.  The problem is, that's going to be really hard to evaluate (or even define).

You can't just go for a flat prior, because the 'no free lunch' theorems say a flat prior over all possible functions on a discrete space means all strategies have the same expected loss.